# Best Way to solve Multi Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

OK,so I have a question about how best to solve a problem in rails. I will show how I have solved it, but would really like some feedback on this approach and if there is something better to do.

To start off, I have a basic ecommerce app with customers, payment methods, and payments.

Now a payment method can be of several different types, EG 'Stripe,Braintree,Paypal'. These are all payment methods but they have very different logic to handle what they do.

Ideally, I would like to be able to call `customer.payment_methods` and receive a relation of payment methods. I would also like to be able to call `customer.stripe_payment_methods` and just get the Stripe methods.

I initially thought of using and STI model but that seems inefficient as each payment method has different columns it depends on.

It seems wasteful to have to store a type field in the table.

Here are the relevant models

```
class PaymentMethod
    scope :stripe, -> {where(type: 'PaymentMethod::Stripe')}
    scope :paypal, -> {where(type: 'PaymentMethod::Paypal')}

    # Lists available payment types
    def self.available_types
        PaymentMethod.subclasses.map { |d| [d::NAME, d.to_s] }
    end
end

class PaymentMethod::Stripe < PaymentMethod
    #performs Stripe specific methods
end

class PaymentMethod::Paypal < PaymentMethod
    #performs Paypal specific actions.
end
```

These all use the `payment_methods` table. This works as I intended it to, but it feels sloppy.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the scopes.

```
PaymentMethod.all         # will get you all payments of any type
PaymentMethod::Stripe.all # will get you only the records using Stripe
PaymentMethod::Paypal.all # will get you only records using Paypal
```

This is not always ideal because of the extra fields. You have a few options:

1) Live with the duplication. Most databases are pretty efficient and it won't waste much space. The issue is more about using them mistakenly in code.

2) Use generic field names and add methods in your subclass to translate to nicer field names

3) Use a JSON field type and add methods in your sub-class to simplify access

4) Separate the fields specific to Stripe into a second table and those specific to Paypal into a third. You will then have a `Payment has_one :tripe` relationship. The downside is that usage gets harder (although you can mitigate this through delegation), more importantly you need to be careful with the performance hit of multiple queries and/or joins.